# Quickly joining 2 list without duplicates

Tags: vb.net, linq

I basically have 2 list of the same object type.
The first one (A,B,C,D) is a property of one of my objects.

I need to join the second list(B, E, F) in my object, but exclude the duplicates.

This means i can't just do:

```
    ListA.AddRange(ListB)
```

I'll have to change it to

```
    ForEach item in ListB
       If Not ListA.Contains(item)
          ListA.Add(item)
       EndIf
    Next
```

Or add:

```
    ListA = ListA.Distinct()
```

Is there a faster and smoother way to code this?

Comment: What is a duplicate? What properties does the type have?

Comment: I have implemented equality members so i'm checking on some internal properties. i can do perform an objA.Equals(objB) to check this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have already overridden the `Equals` and `GetHashcode` you can use [`Enumerable.Union`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358407.aspx) directly:

```
var ListC = ListA.Union(ListB).ToList();
```

Otherwise you could implement `IEqulityCompararer<Foo>` and use `ListA.Union(ListB, comparer)`.

Assuming `Foo` is the type of your class and `Name` is a property you want to use to detect duplicates.

```
public class FooComparer : IEqualityComparer<Foo>
{
    public bool Equals(Foo x, Foo y)
    {
        if (x == null || y == null) return false;
        // 'A' = 'a' just to demonstrate case-insensitive duplicates
        return x.Name.Equals(y.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Foo obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return int.MinValue;
        return obj.Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Now use this comparer for [`Union`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358407.aspx):

```
var ListC = ListA.Union(ListB, new FooComparer()).ToList();
```

Comment: Am i correct that i can just do a Union when i have overriden the Equals and GetHashcode without the custom Comparer. Or does this give any other advantages?

Comment: @JeroenMoonen: Should work also. Then you don't need to use this extra class, just use the overload of `Union` without a custom `IEqualityComparer`.

Comment: @JeroenMoonen: edited my answer accordingly (btw, sorry for VB.NET, i've seen it too late).

Comment: No problem :) thnx for the answer :) just a little syntax difference

Answer (score 0):

there isn't a faster way to do that, since whatever you do you'll need to check every element in both lists to see if it is a duplicate, then you can do it with your own code or use Linq.

Anyway you'll have list1.Count * list2.Count operations